# Is it possible to render a camera view on the Oculus and another on a laptop screen?

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

I am doing an experiment and I need to use a GUI to control it. I want to have one camera view of the game go directly to the Oculus via HDMI and render another view with GUI elements on my laptop screen.

Anyone know any solution to this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If this was a normal app without oculus, you could try to resize the app to fit two screens with extending the desktop and using `Screen.SetResolution` and hacking a few cameras with their viewports matching the screen setup with `Camera.rect`.

With oculus, there should be two render-to-texture cameras and one camera that renders them to the screen. It ought to be possible to modify that last camera to render in only a part of the screen with the `Camera.rect` technique.

For an alternative approach see my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could make another unity3d app with the control panel and comunicate them using either a [plain .net socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [Unity3d Networking](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NetworkReferenceGuide.html) ([RPC](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/net-RPCDetails.html) is best for this)

For an alternative approach see my other answer.